# How to "open" a file in a command line app using the drive.file scope

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have an internal app (not a published one, only used within our Google Workspace domain) which is a command line tool to update the contents of some Google Sheets. It currently uses the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope and works fine.

I want to minimize the privileges of the authorization token that this app caches, and by reading the documentation it seems that I should be able to use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` scope to find the file I want, and also `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` to grant write access to only a specific file.

With the reduced scopes, I am not surprised to get an error like:

```
appNotAuthorizedToFile: The user has not granted the app 566375348811 write access to the file 1UsItGhBHwRaodHbv5g1LCrSESUZBkskDvKDkbGjREjI
```

The only relevant documentation talks about integrating apps with Google Drive and using the Drive Picker UI which I expect does this authorization behind the scenes. Since this is an internal **command line tool**, I really don't want to go that route.

Hence the question:

How do I open a file in a **command line** application using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope?

I'm OK even if I need to set some magic metadata on the file to make it accessible.

### Update

As I got a couple of responses saying that when using `drive.file` it is **not possible** to access files which are not created by the application, I am putting some supporting documentation here to show why I think it is possible:

1. The [API-specific auth info](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/api-specific-auth) is the first document on the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/) page, and it specifically mentions:

> So, when possible, use non-sensitive scopes as they narrow access to
> specific functionality needed by an app. In most cases, providing
> narrow access means using the
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` per-file access scope.

Further [down the page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/api-specific-auth#migrate_an_existing_app_to_a_non-sensitive_scope) it mentions:

> This scope enables users to select the specific files from Google
> Drive, and through the Google Picker, that they want to allow your app
> to access.

I understand this to mean that it **is possible** to open files which were **not** created by the app, even when using `drive.file`.

My problem is that the document goes on to explain:

> Many apps work with per-file access without any changes. If you are
> currently using your own file picker, we recommend switching to the
> [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker) which fully supports the `drive.file` scope.

Well, since I am using a command line app, I cannot use the Google Picker, so I am asking how to implement my own. I do understand that the picker itself needs to have access to all the files (hence the need for a `drive.readonly` scope), but to actually be able to **write** the files, it needs the elevated permission of `drive` or the more restrictive per-file access of `drive.file`.

2. If I simulate an authorization request for `drive.file` I get a prompt which explains that authorizing the request will grant my app to:

> See, edit, create, and delete only the specific Google Drive files **you use** with this app ℹ️

Clicking on the information icon I get a more verbose explanation which reads like it support opening any file I authorize:

> This app wants permission to create new files or **change existing files**
> that you open with this app. Once authorized, the app can:
>
> - See these files
> - Upload and download these files
> - Delete these files
> - See the names and emails of people you share these files with
> - Share and stop sharing these files with others
> - Organize these files
>
> There may be private information in your Google Drive, like financial
> records, medical reports, photos or tax info.

3. There are also other examples of applications like [ZIP Extractor](https://zipextractor.app/) or [diagrams.net](https://app.diagrams.net/) or [Photo Editor](https://overbits.herokuapp.com/photoeditor/) which use the `drive.file` scope (based on the authorization prompt), and which I can use to open **and edit** files that were **not** created by them.

Comment: As [@DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71348215/14271633) refers, with the mentioned scope, you can only access files that have been created using that application, do you find the error outside that condition?

Comment: @Emel I updated my question to explain why I think that this scope also applies to files not created by the app. That's my whole question really - there are guides on how to do this in web based apps (using the Drive Picker) but no documentation about doing it in command line apps. Or implementing my own picker.

Comment: You understand that Google picker is not the Google drive api.  [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker) is a widget that may have features that developers like yourself do not have access to.

Comment: Yes, totally understand that. That's why my problem is that there is this nice limited `drive.file` scope which seems to do exactly what I want (i.e. authorize write access per file instead of granting access to all files), but I cannot find documentation on how to use this limited scope.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as an answer, to demonstrate an ugly "workaround" for the issue.

TL;DR: Use a web based frontend to authorize access to files. Once the app is authorized, the command line app inherits the permissions.

More step by step instructions, assuming we already have a working command line project:

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions and revoke all access I have granted to my app.
2. Follow the instructions at the [Drive Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs) to update my current GCP project.

   1. Create an API key. OK to be unrestricted, but I restricted it to `https://localhost:9843`
   2. Create a new OAuth 2.0 client ID of a "Web application" type (my current one is "Desktop" type and that would not work). Authorize `https://localhost:9843` as a JavaScript origin.
3. Copy the `helloworld.html` example at the bottom of the [Drive Picker API guide](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs) which is [also on GitHub](https://github.com/googleworkspace/browser-samples/blob/master/drive/picker/helloworld.html) with the following modifications:

   1. Set `developerKey` to the API key created above
   2. Set `clientId` to the new OAuth 2.0 client ID created abovce
   3. Set `appId` to the numeric project ID of my GCP project
   4. Add `'include_granted_scopes': true` to the call to `window.gapi.auth.authorize`
   5. Update `createPicker` to make it easier to find the files I want. E.g., set the mime type filter to `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`.
4. Host the example in a browser with `ruby -rwebrick/https -e 'WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 9843, :DocumentRoot => ".", :SSLEnable => true, :SSLCertName => "CN=localhost", :SSLCertComment => "Autogenerated" ).start'`

Now, if my command line app fails to edit a file, I can use https://localhost:9843/helloworld.html to grant access to the file, and my command line app can then edit that file.

Answer (score -1):

If you check the docs for the [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive) you will find it says.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have **opened or created with this app**

This gives your app access to files that the app itself created or has previously opened.

You should also know that there is no way to limit authorization to a single file.   Authorization is all or not thing.

> How do I open a file in a command line application using the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file scope?

You make sure that the file was created by the app itself.  using files.create.  If the file was created by any other app  the you cant access it using the drive.file scope

There is one note though if you have https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.read-only scope and you open that file to read it.  the line where it says **opened or created with this app** implies to me that once you have opended it for read in this app that you would then be able to use it with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`  but its not something I have tried.

Another thing is im not sure what you mean by open the google drive api is a file storage api its not going to let you see the contents of the file your going to have to download it and open it locally.  Have you considered going though the Google sheets api if you want to read and write to it programmatically?

Comment: My interpretation of the *opened or created with this app* is that I have access to files I have created, or to files I have authorized (i.e., "opened") specifically. The documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth also seems to confirm that: `In most cases, providing narrow access means using the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file per-file access scope.` (emphasis on `per-file`). My problem is that there is no documentation on how to use this scope efficiently for command line apps.

Comment: As there are two people saying that this is not possible with the `drive.file` scope, I updated my question to explain why I think that this is technically possible (with a web-based app), but unfortunately I am working with a command line app.

Comment: @chutz it doesnt matter if its command line this has no effect on it.

Comment: What language are you using to write this command line tool?

Comment: To answer the question, using ruby at the moment, but the language is irrelevant. Anyway, as I tried to point out in my update, I am aware of plenty of tools which only use the `drive.file` scope and do not require the file be created using them. https://overbits.herokuapp.com/photoeditor/ is a very obvious example of editing images created by a different app.

Comment: Im not sure i understand your point.  If you check the documentation [file.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) to create a file you need to use one of the following scopes ```https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive```,
```https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file```, or
```https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata```   The app you have posted appears to be using the full drive scope of ```https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive```.

Comment: I personally dont bother using ```https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file``` All of the apps i have developed for clients have always used ```https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive```

Comment: All the apps I posted do **not** use the full `drive` scope.

I checked their scopes while authorizing, and also at https://myaccount.google.com/permissions. They can only "See, edit, create, and delete only the specific Google Drive files you use with this app". An app with the full `drive` scope would otherwise be able to "See, edit, create, and delete all of your Google Drive files".

I understand that using the full `drive` scope is one way to move forward, I am doing that already. But I came here looking for help to minimize the privileges of the cached token that my app uses.

Comment: Sounds like you knew you would need to use the full drive scope, you were just hoping there was another way.   I understand that you want to make you system reliant on fewer permissions but these are the permissions google gives us.   I believe I commented about the same issue more then ten years ago on their issue forum.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my whole purpose for this question is to avoid storing tokens with privileges higher than necessary. If this cannot be done, I'll accept a supporting reference as the answer. Furthermore, I still disagree with the claim in your answer that `If the file was created by any other app the you cant access it using the drive.file scope` as there are plenty of examples of apps that do exactly that. I mean... in theory I could use the Drive Picker UI to authorize access to the file, then pass and cache the token in my command line tool and I am pretty certain it would work...

Comment: The documentation states **Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app**  this means if it has been opened by the app you should be able to access it.   My personal experience was that if it wasn't created by the app i couldn't open it in the first place.   This is my experience i encourage you to try yourself they may have fixed it since i last tried.   I have been considering trying and doing a YouTube video on your question 

Comment: Well, I did verify my suspicion and posted it as an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71422763/1213346. I hope it helps you in your Youtubing adventures . I just wish there was a less ugly way to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: LOL we are talking about free apis here there is no less ugly,  but have a +1 for your creativity.